# Chrome DevTools debugger is slow when debugging exclusively my JavaScript code

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, debugging, knockout.js, google-chrome-devtools

DevTools Chrome (and Edge) debugger steps are very slow and do not highlight variable values ​​on tooltip while debugging the JavaScript code of my application (ASP.Net MVC5 + React + Knockout.js). The whole DevTools is slow while debugging. **Although when I debug the JavaScriopt code of an external library (like jQuery) on the same source tab, everything works quickly and the variables on the tooltip are highlighted well.**

Clearing the cache, reinstalling the browser, and so on did not help.
Chrome Canary same problem.